# How to force GitLab to run a complete pipeline before starting a new one?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have one runner associated with my project to avoid concurrent build. GitLab to process the complete pipeline before start a new one?

concurrent is set to = 1 (config file of the runner)

```
before_script:
  - echo %CI_COMMIT_SHA%
  - echo %CI_PROJECT_DIR%

stages:
  - createPBLs
  - build
  - package


create PBLs:
  stage: createPBLs
  script: 
    - md "C:\HierBauen\%CI_COMMIT_SHA%\"
    - xcopy /y /s "C:/Bauen" "C:/HierBauen/%CI_COMMIT_SHA%"
    - xcopy /y /s "%CI_PROJECT_DIR%" "C:\HierBauen\%CI_COMMIT_SHA%"
    - cd "C:\HierBauen\%CI_COMMIT_SHA%"
    - ./run_orcascript.cmd
  only:
  - tags
  - master

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - cd "C:\HierBauen\%CI_COMMIT_SHA%"
  - ./run_pbc.cmd
  only:
  - tags
  except:
  - master

build_master:
  stage: build
  script:
  - cd "C:\HierBauen\%CI_COMMIT_SHA%"
  - ./run_pbcm.cmd
  only:
  - master

package:
  stage: package
  script:
  - cd "C:\HierBauen\%CI_COMMIT_SHA%"
  - ./cpfiles.cmd
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - GitLab-Build
    name: "%CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME%"
  only:
  - tags
  - master
```

Unfortunately, the earlier started pipeline is disturbed by a new started pipeline. As a result, the build is flawed at the end ...

**EDIT new config file:**

```
before_script:
  - echo %CI_BUILD_REF%
  - echo %CI_PROJECT_DIR%
  - xcopy /y /s "C:/Bauen" "%CI_PROJECT_DIR%"

stages:
  - createPBLs
  - build
  - package


create PBLs:
  stage: createPBLs
  script: 
    - ./run_orcascript.cmd
  only:
  - tags
  - master


build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - ./run_pbc.cmd
  only:
  - tags
  except:
  - master


build_master:
  stage: build
  script:
  - ./run_pbcm.cmd



  only:
  - master

package:
  stage: package
  script:
  - ./cpfiles.cmd
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    name: "%CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME%"
    paths:
      - GitLab-Build
  only:
  - tags
  - master
```

Comment: Can't be done natively. The last (hopefully) relevant open issue on gitlab.com: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/202186
Two workarounds are mentioned:
https://gitlab.com/Istador/gitlab-ci-orchestrator and
https://pypi.org/project/gitlab-job-guard/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently there is no way for this, and there is an [open issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/16548) at the moment on GitLab.

What you can do instead is to add `limit = 1` in your gitlab-runner `config.toml` file, which would enforce the gitlab-runner to only accept one job at a time.

I see that you are not passing artifacts between your stages, but if your `build` stage, depended on anything in the `createPBLs` stage, you can use
a combination of[artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts) and [dependencies](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#dependencies) to pass data between stages.

---

For example:

```
before_script:
  - echo %CI_COMMIT_SHA%
  - echo %CI_PROJECT_DIR%

stages:
  - createPBLs
  - build
  - package


create PBLs:
  stage: createPBLs
  script: 
    - md "C:\HierBauen\%CI_COMMIT_SHA%\"
    - xcopy /y /s "C:/Bauen" "C:/HierBauen/%CI_COMMIT_SHA%"
    - xcopy /y /s "%CI_PROJECT_DIR%" "C:\HierBauen\%CI_COMMIT_SHA%"
    - cd "C:\HierBauen\%CI_COMMIT_SHA%"
    - ./run_orcascript.cmd
  artifacts:
    name: createPBLS_%CI_COMMIT_SHA%
    untracked: true
    expire_in: 1 day
  only:
  - tags
  - master

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - cd "C:\HierBauen\%CI_COMMIT_SHA%"
  - ./run_pbc.cmd
  dependencies:
  - createPBLs
  artifacts:
    name: build_%CI_COMMIT_SHA%
    untracked: true
    expire_in: 1 day
  only:
  - tags
  except:
  - master

build_master:
  stage: build
  script:
  - cd "C:\HierBauen\%CI_COMMIT_SHA%"
  - ./run_pbcm.cmd
  dependencies:
  - createPBLs
  artifacts:
    name: build_%CI_COMMIT_SHA%
    untracked: true
    expire_in: 1 day
  only:
  - master

package:
  stage: package
  script:
  - cd "C:\HierBauen\%CI_COMMIT_SHA%"
  - ./cpfiles.cmd
  dependencies:
  - build_master
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - GitLab-Build
    name: "%CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME%"
  only:
  - tags
  - master
```

Comment: this is bad. How could I rebuild the pipeline so that two different pipelines can not get in each other's way? Artifacts can only be tapped from the runner in workspace, correct?

Comment: @Hendouz Yes, I've updated the answer to give an example

Comment: Be aware, that the artifacts will be uploaded to the GitLab server, so this could take some time - edit what gets uploaded so only the essential components are moved between stages.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. However, I have the following problem: As you can see, my project is not built in the workspace of the runner, but in another directory. There are also the build scripts (eg run_orcascript.cmd, run_pbc.cmd, /run_pbcm.cmd). You say above: untracked: true. So these files are also tracked? Can gitlab-ci / runner ever access untracked: true in a directory other than its own, where it pulls the repository? @Rekovni

Comment: @Hendouz Ah, you may have issues with using GitLab runners, as ideally the builds would all be contained in its own build directory if that makes sense. If it is possible, you could do a `before_script` and copy across all the files you need to run the build? (so it's not reliant on those outside the build). Otherwise, you will always hit this issue of the two pipelines hitting each other trying to make the same changes as you've found.

Comment: I have a problem: I configured it to pull the batches into workspace via before_script. However, after the create_PBL is through and he is in the next job (eg build_master), the workspace reloads and deletes the files created by create_PBL? the script /run_pbcm.cmd is dependent on the step of create_PBL. I edit the current config again purely.

Comment: Can one adjust it so that he pulls only once per pipeline? (eg in the first stage only once) @Rekovni

Comment: No; but you should now implement what I edited in yesterday with the artifacts and dependencies, so that any changes to the workspace is not affected

Comment: the problem is, if I write "untracked: true" then the batches are also given or not? how can I avoid that

Comment: If you know what files you want moved between stages, you can use wildcards to select the files you want.

Comment: Many Thanks. I have now solved this easier: from 3 stages I have now just made a stage: Build. That's it. @Rekovni

Comment: This is simply a total mess. All issues in regards to this problem are years old with hundreds of upvotes and no outcome at all.

Comment: @Hendouz: Q: "How could I rebuild the pipeline so that two different pipelines can not get in each other's way?" A: Use a docker executor otherwise it gets way too complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `resource_group` feature, which provides a way to group jobs which need the same mutex wrapped around them. Out of the box, `resource_group`s don't provide this pipeline-level mutexing (concurrency prevention), however, using the [process mode](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/resource_groups/#process-modes) option, specifically setting it to "oldest first", does.
[The docs further state](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/resource_groups/#change-the-process-mode) that:

> To change the process mode of a resource group, you must use the API and send a request to edit an existing resource group by specifying the process_mode:
>
> ```
> unordered
> oldest_first
> newest_first
> ```

Also mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74286510/532621